# Number of different groups given a list of repeating digits

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, integer-partitions

Suppose that you are given the list`[1,1,2,2]` . The different groups that can be formed with this list are -

```
[11,22],[1,122],[1,1,22],[1,1,2,2],[1,12,2],[112,2],[11,22],[12,12],[11,2,2]
```

The total number of different groups is 9.

If I am given an arbitrary number of 1's and 2's, how would I find the number of different groups that can be formed?

Comment: Why $[12,12]$ but not $[21,21]$? I don't get how these groups are formed.

Comment: @guest123 Why does $[11,22]$ appear twice?

Comment: @bof Yes, that would give the correct answer.

Comment: @bof Given that there is no simple expression for the number of partitions of an integer (the simplified case you suggested where we just have $n$ 1s), it seems wildly implausible that there is a simple answer to the OP's question. I suspect the best one could hope for is an infinite product as a generating function.

Comment: It appears that the $1$s and $2$s don't matter; we're just inserting commas into a string of 4 characters. There are $2^{4-1}=8$ ways to do this. The OP has three errors in his list. [1122] fails to appear, [11,22] appears twice, and [12,12] is the only one that rearranges items. I'm guessing it shouldn't be there.

Comment: @GTonyJacobs Yes, if it was just a question of inserting commas, the answer would be easy. One of his [11,22]s is presumably meant to be [1122], as bof pointed out. But if [12,12] is intended, then the problem is far more difficult. But the OP appears to have gone away, so I guess we wait for his return.

Comment: Oooooohhhh. I see it now.

Comment: How you're reading the question. I was misunderstanding it before, I think. Sorry for not making that clear. I have no idea how to solve the question that I'm now seeing.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, $[11,22]$ is listed twice; I'm guessing one of those was supposed to be $[1122].$

The question is not stated very clearly. Here's how I interpret it:

Let $S=\{(m,n)\in\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z:m,n\ge0\}.$ Given $(m,n)\in S,$ determine $f(m,n),$ the number of ways in which the vector $(m,n)$ can be expressed as an unordered sum of elements of $S\setminus\{(0,0)\}$, i.e., the number of partitions of the "bipartite number" $(m,n).$

Equivalently, if $p,q$ are distinct prime numbers, $f(m,n)$ is the number of factorizations of $p^mq^n,$ where a factorization of a positive integer $x$ is a nonincreasing sequence of integers greater than $1$ whose product is equal to $x.$ For example, if $x=36=2^2\cdot3^2,$ the $f(2,2)=9$ factorizations are
$$36=18\cdot2=12\cdot3=9\cdot4=9\cdot2\cdot2=6\cdot6=6\cdot3\cdot2=4\cdot3\cdot3=3\cdot3\cdot2\cdot2.$$

The connection with factorizations is somewhat obscured by the OP's notation, but it will be clearer if we change the OP's $1$ and $2$ to $p$ and $q$ (standing for two distinct primes), after correcting the second $[11,22]$ to $[1122]$, namely:
$$[11,22]\sim(p^2)(q^2)$$
$$[1,122]\sim(p)(pq^2)$$
$$[1,1,22]\sim(p)(p)(q^2)$$
$$[1,1,2,2]\sim(p)(p)(q)(q)$$
$$[1,12,2]\sim(p)(pq)(q)$$
$$[112,2]\sim(p^2q)(q)$$
$$[1122]\sim(p^2q^2)$$
$$[12,12]\sim(pq)(pq)$$
$$[11,2,2]\sim(p^2)(q)(q)$$

$f(0,n)=p(n),$ the [number of partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)) of $n,$ is [OEIS sequence A000041](https://oeis.org/A000041).

$f(1,n)=\sum_{k=0}^np(k)$ is [OEIS sequence A000070](https://oeis.org/A000070).

$f(2,n)=\sum_{k=0}^n\left\lfloor\frac{k+4}2\right\rfloor p(n-k)$ is [OEIS sequence A000291 "Number of bipartite partitions of $n$ white objects and $2$ black ones"](https://oeis.org/A000291); thus, for example,
$$f(2,2)=\left\lfloor\frac42\right\rfloor p(2)+\left\lfloor\frac52\right\rfloor p(1)+\left\lfloor\frac62\right\rfloor p(0)=2\cdot2+2\cdot1+3\cdot1=9.$$

$f(3,n)$ is [OEIS sequence A000412 "Number of bipartite partitions of $n$ white objects and $3$ black ones"](https://oeis.org/A000412).

See [OEIS sequence A000465](https://oeis.org/A000465) for $f(4,n),$ [A000491](https://oeis.org/A000491) for $f(5,n),$ [A002755](https://oeis.org/A002755) for $f(6,n),$ [A002756](https://oeis.org/A002756) for $f(7,n),$ [A002757](https://oeis.org/A002757) for $f(8,n),$ [A002758](https://oeis.org/A002758) for $f(9,n),$ [A002759](https://oeis.org/A002759) for $f(10,n).$

$f(n,n)$ is [OEIS sequence A002774 "Number of bipartite partitions of $n$ white objects and $n$ black ones"](https://oeis.org/A002774); among the references given by the OEIS is [F. C. Auluck, "On partitions of bipartite numbers"](https://oeis.org/A002774/a002774_1.pdf), Mathematical Proceedings of the Cambridge Philosophical Society, Volume 49, Issue 01, January 1953, pp. 72-83.

The general problem is discussed in a 2008 paper by Shamik Ghosh, "Counting number of factorizations of a natural number" ([arXiv:0811.3479](http://arxiv.org/abs/0811.3479)) with a bibliography of nine items.